# Twitter´s bootstrap fixed black menu on the top: it won´t work on mobile IF it has submenues. Workaround?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

Is there ant workaround to fix the problem with the black navbar that´s fixed on the top of twitter´s bootstrap, that doesn´t work with submenues on mobile?

When you access from a smaller screen, the page with that fixed navbar transform in a single button, aligned to the left. When you click it appears the whole navbar menu as a list.
If that menu has submenues, when you click that single button, nothing happens.

What can I do with that? Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dropdowns for sub menus:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="">
            <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search">
          </form>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
  </div><!-- /navbar -->
```